# How many 4-digit numbers $abcd$ are there such that $a < b < c < d$ and $b - a < c - b < d - c$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Trial and error

a = 1, b = 2, c = 4, d = --X

a = 1, b = 2, c = 4, d = 7

a = 1, b = 2, c = 4, d = 8

a = 1, b = 2, c = 4, d = 9

a = 1, b = 2, c = 5, d = 9

a = 1, b = 3, c = 6, d = --X

a = 2, b = 3, c = 5 d = 8

a = 2, b = 3, c = 5 d = 9

a = 2, b = 3, c = 6, d = -- X

a = 2, b = 3, c = 6, d = 9

I am not getting it .. Is there a better method other than trial-error?

Comment: HINT: We can construct $\binom{9}{4}$ different $a<b<c<d$ values and the least $b-a=1$ and the most $c-b=5$

Comment: $2369$ doesn't satisfy the condition

Comment: What you have showed doesn't seems trial-error. Looks methodical enough to reduce the calculations to a minimal.

Answer (score -1):

Since $abcd$ is a four-digit positive integer, $a, b, c, d$ are integers which satisfy the inequalities $1 \leq a < b < c < d \leq 9$.

Since $a < b$, $b - a \geq 1 \implies b \geq a + 1$.

Since $b - a < c - b$, $c - b \geq 2 \implies c \geq b + 2 \geq a + 1 + 2 = a + 3$.

Since $c - b < d - c$, $d - c \geq 3 \implies d \geq c + 3 \geq b + 2 + 3 = b + 5 \geq a + 1 + 5 \geq a + 6$.

Observe that if $a > 3$, then $d \geq a + 6 > 9$.  Hence, $a \leq 3$.

If $a = 3$, then $b \geq a + 1 \geq 4$, $c \geq b + 2 \geq a + 3 \geq 6$, and $d \geq c + 3 \geq b + 5 \geq a + 6 = 9$, which can only occur if
$$a = 3, b = 4, c = 6, d = 9$$

Observe that if $b - a = 2$, then $c - b \geq 3$ and $d - c \geq 4 \implies d \geq a + 2 + 3 + 4 > 9$.  Thus, $b - a = 1 \implies b = a + 1$.

Thus, if $a = 2$, then $b = 3$, $c \geq a + 3 \geq 5$, and $d \geq a + 6 \geq 8$.  Moreover, since $9 \geq d \geq c + 3$, $c \leq 6$.

- If $c = 6$, then $c - b = 3 \implies d - c \geq 4 \implies d \geq c + 4 \geq 6 + 4 > 9$, which is impossible.
- If $c = 5$, then $c - b = 2 \implies d - c \geq 3 \implies d \geq c + 3 \geq 5 + 3 \geq 8$.  Since $d \leq 9$, the only possibilities are $d = 8$ or $d = 9$.

Therefore, there are two possibilities when $a = 2$:
\begin{align*}
a & = 2, b = 3, c = 5, d = 8\\
a & = 2, b = 3, c = 5, d = 9
\end{align*}

If $a = 1$, $b = 2$, $c \geq a + 3 \geq 4$, and $d \geq a + 6 \geq 7$.  Moreover, since $9 \geq d \geq c + 3$, $c \leq 6$.

- If $c = 6$, then $c - b = 4 \implies d - c \geq 5 \implies d \geq c + 5 \geq 6 + 5 > 9$, which is impossible.
- If $c = 5$, then $c - b = 3 \implies d - c \geq 4$.  Since $d \geq c + 4 \geq 5 + 4 = 9$ and $d \leq 9$, the only possibility is that $d = 9$.
- If $c = 4$, then $c - b = 2 \implies d - c \geq 3$.  Thus, $d \geq 4 + 3 = 7$.  Since $d = 9$, the only possibilities are $d = 7$, $d = 8$, or $d = 9$.

Therefore, there are four possibilities when $a = 1$.:
\begin{align*}
a & = 1, b = 2, c = 4, d = 7\\
a & = 1, b = 2, c = 4, d = 8\\
a & = 1, b = 2, c = 4, d = 9\\
a & = 1, b = 2, c = 5, d = 9
\end{align*}

Hence, there are $7$ numbers which satisfy the stated conditions:
$$1247, 1248, 1249, 1259, 2358, 2359, 3469$$

Comment: $1258$ doesn't satisfies the condition.

Comment: $2369$ doesn't satisfies the conditions.

Comment: @jjagmath  When I stepped away from the computer, I realized that I had made the errors you pointed out since I had not finished my analysis of the problem.